# AngularJS - Filtering minus symbol from front end

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I have a `$scope.myNumber`, which can be any positive or negative value (e.g. `-212`, `-31`, `0`, `31` or `123`), and which I display via:

```
{{ myNumber }}
```

How can I add a filter to this, so that it removes the `-` (minus) symbol?

Comment: Did you try `Math.abs(myNumber)`

Comment: @PSL - Yes, and that works when in my JS file (controller), can i do this in the HTML code?

Comment: Yep, simply do `$scope.abs = Math.abs;` in your controller, and `{{abs(myNumber)}}` in your template.

Comment: The documentation has a section titles "Creating custom filters". Why don't you read it and try something? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: I would add it as an answer, but it is already at the comments. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/425wb/

Answer (score 8):

Another approach which seems better to me is to create a filter, like:

```
app.filter('abs', function () {
  return function(val) {
    return Math.abs(val);
  }
});
```

and then use it by

```
{{ myNumber | abs}}
```